# Windows Server 2016 "Failed to register the service principal name"

Tags: active-directory, hyper-v, windows-server-2016

I have a Windows Server 2016 virtual host which is hosting a virtual domain controller, and a few additional servers. When the physical host needs to reboot for scheduled patching, upon startup the server receives the following errors:

"Failed to register the service principal name 'Hyper-V Replica Service'.
Failed to register the service principal name 'Microsoft Virtual System Migration Service'.
Failed to register the service principal name 'Microsoft Virtual Console Service'."

Service principal names are properly set in the attributes of AD of the host for each of the respective SPN's, and I'm unsure how to trace this out any further. Does anyone have any first hand experience or recommendations in regards to this? There are also no NTDS port restrictions in place.

Comment: Do you have only one AD DC, which is running as VM inside "rebooted" physical host? I assume Windows Server 2016 is in the domain, and there no active DC, when it starts.

Comment: You are entirely correct, my first initial thought was that the when the host restarts, it then attempts to register SPN's, but the virtualized DC isn't available yet, so those errors get generated and then auto-resolve once the DC is available. 
But yes you are correct. Any tips on resolving these errors, or are they really just informational, and to resolve this would it require a secondary DC or something along those lines? Sorry for word vomit, just excited that someone knew exactly what the setup was/is.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Active Directory, select view Advanced Features. On the Hyper-V host computer Security Tab/Advanced select the SELF principal/EDIT and allow permission for  "Validated write to service principal name".